# Is there regularization term which is simply a linear function of $\beta$?

Tags: regression, regularization

there have been a lot of discussions on regularization in the linear regression context:

$\min( (A*\beta -y)^2 + \lambda |\beta|_{0,1,2})$

L0 regularization is counting the number of non-zero beta

L1 is absolute value

L2 is square

I am curious why I have never heard about regularization term that is simply a linear function of $\beta$

$\min( (A*\beta -y)^2 + \lambda \beta)$

My questions are:

1) most importantly, is there any theoretical flaw of the linear regularizer?

2) if not, what's the best way to solve this?

Comment: Generally speaking, we'd want the penalty to be nonnegative so that blowing up $\beta$ feasible

Comment: Hint: *try it and see*

Answer (score 3):

$\beta$ is a vector, and we need to map it to a scalar to minimize the weighted sum of the error (or negative log-likelihood) and this scalar.

The canonical way to go about this is to use a [norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_(mathematics)) of $\beta$. As you write, different norms imply that the minimizer has different properties.

Comment: If I could further add, you could do a linear function technically of the form

$$ \lambda 1_p^\top \beta $$

Since most optimization algorithms only require convexity and continuity of the penalty part (from what I have seen). But even so, that has issues as it only imposes a penalty on the sum and not on the size of the coefficients.

Comment: @Josh: indeed. For instance, if $\lambda>0$, then one could minimize the criterion by letting $\beta\to -\infty$, which is probably not what we want.

Answer (score 2):

If you meant to use $\lambda \sum \beta$ as your penalty term, this will have the problem that your algorithm will try to make the $\beta$ values as *negative* as possible consistent with a reasonable fit to the data (not *as small in magnitude* as possible, which is probably what you want). As @StephanKolassa points out in a comment above, letting $\beta \to -\infty$ would likely minimize the criterion. (A tiny bit of analysis would be required to actually prove this; you'd need to show that (for a particular value of $\lambda$) the magnitude of the derivative of $\|X\beta-y\|^2$ is smaller than the derivative of $\lambda \sum \beta$ ...)

Comment: For some value of $\lambda$ it will always be;)

Comment: but is it generally true for $\lambda>0$? @StephanKolassa implies it is. I don't doubt it, but I haven't thought it through.

Comment: No (unless I am misreading you): the proposed loss function is continuous, so we can always find a small neighborhood of $\lambda = 0^+$ where the solution (of the proposed loss function) is arbitrarily close to the OLS solution, whatever the OLS solution is. $\lambda$ has to be larger than some cut-off for $\beta=-\infty$ to be solution of that proposed loss function for that particular problem.

Answer (score 1):

Stephan Kolassa has a nice answer.

In addition, there are some problems in your math.

The first problem is mixing $A$ and $\beta$.

A better notation can be

$$
\text{minimize}~~ \|X\beta-y\|^2+\lambda\|\beta\|^2
$$

or

$$
\text{minimize}~~ \|Ax-b\|^2+\lambda\|x\|^2
$$

If data matrix is represented with $A$ then $x$ is paired with. And if data matrix is represented with $X$, $\beta$ is paired with. In both settings, $\|\cdot\|$ represent vector norm.

In addition, people usually do not use $*$ on matrix multiplication.

Finally, in your equation, It is hard to see $(A*\beta -y)^2 $ is a scalar. If it is a vector $\min$ on a vector is not clearly defined. I think this is the root of your confusion. As Stephan Kolassa mentioned, usually, objective function returns a scalar.